# Xamarin UItest - is it possible to check the value of the element?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I'm new to Xaramin UItest.
I'm currently writing a short script for an app and I'm trying to check whether the value of a element matches correctly.
So for example, when I buy 2 items that is worth $7 each it should show $14 on a string and I'm trying to check whether the string is showing $14 correctly.
Currently I'm using

```
app.Query(x => x.Id("text_total").Text("$14"));
```

But the test is passing even if the value and the Text are different.

Any tips on how to make this work?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the `Text` value of the results of the `Query` by using an NUnit `Assert`:

```
var results = app.Query(x => x.Id("text_total");
Assert.AreEqual("$14", results[0].Text);
```

If the Text value is different from the expected "$14", this particular test will fail and the next test (`[Test]` attributed method) will run.